# YouTube API - Historical Video Views on Channel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to extract the activity on a company YouTube channel going back 5+ years.  I ran into an issue with the YouTube Analytics API as it is limiting me to the last 30 days of activity.  I am thinking of trying the YouTube Data API V3 next, but want to first ask here if anyone knows how to pull the deep historical data from a YouTube channel.   I am interested primarily in the number of views per video per day.  I am using Google Cloud Platform and need to store the data in BigQuery.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube Data API will only give you the current numbers from the channel/videos, not the historical data. For that you will need to use the Analytics API.

In order to get the full data for each video you will need to hit the [analytics reports query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query) and use filters and parameters to get the data you need. Specifically for what you mentioned in the question, take a look in the **startDate** and **endDate** parameters and use the [day dimension](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions#day) to aggregate the data. You will also need to use the **videoId** to filter the data (and to get a list of video_ids you can use the data API).

I am currently getting data for the last 5+ years. Just an example here by getting 2017 information:
[image: Historical dates views]

Answer (score 0):

As YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide this basic feature, I would recommend you to try on your own to get the data your are looking for:

By requesting the YouTube studio `Video analytics` webpage of a video interesting you:

https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics

Below the `Views` chart, click on `SEE MORE`.

Then open your web browser Network tab (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>). Make sure to filter XHR requests.

Then select `Since uploaded (lifetime)` for the time range.

You should be able to see a request to `join` endpoint, copy it as cURL by right-clicking it.

To use this request for another given video, think about modifying the video id of the JSON `--data-raw` argument at `/nodes/1/value/query/restricts/0/inValues` and to also modify `/nodes/1/value/query/timeRange/dateIdRange/inclusiveStart` to the upload date of the video (retrievable with YouTube Data API v3) in the format `yyyymmdd`.